# Finding planes intersecting along a specific line

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, plane-geometry

I have a plane $V$ (it's basis) in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and a vector $a$ that belongs to that plane. What should I do when I want to find all planes that intersect $V$ along the line created by $a$? How would I calculate that? I tried visalising some examples:

$$V=\Bigg\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}\Bigg\}\quad a=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

In this case I think there is an infinite number of planes that intersect $V$ along that line - there is one plane that is orthogonal to $V$ and then there are many, many planes that intersect $V$ under an angle - please tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: By "the line created by a" you mean "at" for all real numbers, t, x= t, y= t, z= 0, right? Essentially, you would "visualize" this as a single plane containing that line, rotated around that line.  Any plane can be written Ax+ By+ Cz= 0.  Such a plane contains the line if and only if At+ Bt= (A+ B)t= 0 for all t which means that B= -A.  That is, Ax- Ay+ Cz= 0 or (provided that C is not 0) z= (A/C)(x- y).  Replace the constant A/C by, say, D to get z= D(x- y) or x- y- (1/D)z= 0, the single parameter, D, determining which plane.

Comment: I think you're right. Take the original plane and rotate it about the line L = $ta$.

Answer (score 1):

I solve your example ( and I hope you can find from this the general method).

In your case the line ''created by $a$ '' is the intersection of the two planes:
$$
\begin{cases}
x-y=0\\
z=0
\end{cases}
$$
All the planes (the bundle of planes) that contains such line  are represented by the linear combination of the two planes:
$$
\lambda(x-y)+\mu z=0
$$

Note that for $\lambda=0$ we find the plane $V$.